# validação filter_input php

Tags: php

Estou a receber por `$_POST` gostaria de saber se é errado fazer a validação do `if` deste modo.

```
$romaneio = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'romaneio');

if($romaneio == ''){
    $romaneio = 'null';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem nada de errado com sua condição, o que é interessando observar é o seguinte, o `PHP` já considera uma condição como `false` no seguintes casos:

- null
- 0
- array()
- ""

Considerando que você faça a seguinte atribuição:

```
$romaneio = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'romaneio');
```

Você pode simplesmente colocar sua variável numa condição e usa-la normalmente caso não seja considerada `false`:

```
if($romaneio){ //simples assim, sem precisar de comparação
    //e no bloco você a utiliza como quiser
} else { //else opcional caso queira setar algo como no exemplo da pergunta
    $romaneio = 'null';
}
```

Ou até mesmo como você colocou na pergunta, mas simplesmente "negando" a condição:

```
if(!$romaneio){
    $romaneio = 'null'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O `filter_input`, além de trazer o resultado, também faz a validação do campo, trazendo `FALSE`. Recomendo fazer:

```
if (!filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'romaneio')) {
    $romaneio = 'null';
}
```

Comment: Ok, mas preciso que `'romaneio'` seja atribuida a uma variavel se não for null.

Comment: Pode colocar no `else`.